# how to get values of several dropdown lists from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, jstl

i have a question when i try to capture the value of dropdown list from jsp file to servlet.

```
        <select name="extraroom">
            <c:if test="${booking.roomType ne 'single'}">
                <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${booking.count}">
                    <option value="<c:out value="${i}"/>"><c:out value="${i}"/></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
        </select>
```

i use Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("extraroom"))

i have many drop down lists according to different roomType.
but the result in java servlet always get the value of the first dropdown lists...

what should i change in servlet?

Thank you.

Comment: Post more code to have a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: show all select box and sertlet code how you capture?

Answer (score 0):

For a select to be retrieved by a server the select has to

1. be inside a form and
2. have a unique name identifier inside (it; best the identifier is unqiue across the entire DOM tree)